# Template Literals for Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When i try to put an array into a JavaScript array, a la,

```
> `${[1,2,3]}`
```

I get back this

```
'1,2,3'
```

and not

```
'[1,2,3]'
```

in the latest Node & Chrome.

I am missing something incredibly obvious, but need it spelled out to me nevertheless : )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

Comment: You are getting the string interpretation of an array, so a join with comma separated values, change it to `\`[${[1, 2, 3]}]\`` should do it

Comment: what ever object you use, its `toString()` gets called. `Array.toString()` returns a string of comma separated items of the array.

Comment: I'm missing why you would expect this to get that non-obvious result? Template literals are not `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the default, the values that are interpolated into a template literal are converted to their string representation.

For objects that means calling their `.toString()` method. The string representation of an array is simply a comma separated list of the strings representation of its elements, without leading `[` or trailing `]`:

```js
console.log(
  [1,2,3].toString()
);
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use `JSON.stringify(array)`
It can help you to predict conversion to the string any arrays in this array.

```js
const array = [["expected","test",1],0];
const arrayStr = JSON.stringify(array);
const templateResAsString = `${array}`; // expected,test,1,0
const templateResAsarray = `${arrayStr}`; // [["expected","test",1],0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consolodiated list including above answers:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,'foo','bar','baz']


console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
console.log(arr.toString());
console.log(`${arr}`);
console.log(arr.join('\n'));
```

Good Luck...